# HibernateException: Errors in named queries: what is the possible cause?

Tags: hibernate, named-query

I have an issue with named queries. Firstly, I want to understand a possible set of causes that can be a reason (something beyound syntax errors). Secondly, I would be glad to hear your queses about possible solution. Thanks in advance.

I have a NamedQuery:

```
        @NamedQuery(name = "HotelsEntity.findAllWithFilter",
            query = "select h from HotelsEntity h " +
                    /*"left join fetch h.reservationDates hReservationDates " +*/
                    "left join fetch h.property hProperty " +
                    "left join fetch h.rooms hRooms " +
                    "left join fetch hRooms.inventory inventory " +
                    "left join fetch inventory.reservation reservation " +
                    "where " +
                    "hProperty.hasPool = :pool " +
                        "AND hProperty.hasTennisCourt = :tennis " +
                        "AND hProperty.hasWaterslides = :waterslides " +
                        "AND hRooms.peopleCapacity >= :capacity " +
                        "AND hRooms.locked = false " +
                        "AND (" +
                            "(reservation.checkIn <= :checkin AND reservation.checkOut >= :checkin) " +
                            "OR " +
                            "(reservation.checkIn >= :checkin AND reservation.checkOut <= :checkout) " +
                            "OR " +
                            "(reservation.checkIn >= :checkin AND reservation.checkOut >= :checkout) )"),
```

And it works. I want to add one more join to ReservationDatesEntity:

```
        @NamedQuery(name = "HotelsEntity.findAllWithFilter",
            query = "select h from HotelsEntity h " +
                    "left join fetch h.reservationDates hReservationDates " +
                    "left join fetch h.property hProperty " +
                    "left join fetch h.rooms hRooms " +
                    "left join fetch hRooms.inventory inventory " +
                    "left join fetch inventory.reservation reservation " +
                    "where " +
                    "hProperty.hasPool = :pool " +
                        "AND hProperty.hasTennisCourt = :tennis " +
                        "AND hProperty.hasWaterslides = :waterslides " +
                        "AND hRooms.peopleCapacity >= :capacity " +
                        "AND hRooms.locked = false " +
                        "AND (" +
                            "(reservation.checkIn <= :checkin AND reservation.checkOut >= :checkin) " +
                            "OR " +
                            "(reservation.checkIn >= :checkin AND reservation.checkOut <= :checkout) " +
                            "OR " +
                            "(reservation.checkIn >= :checkin AND reservation.checkOut >= :checkout) )"),
```

And it failed with `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: HotelsEntity.findAllWithFilter`. What can be a reason of erros in named queries?

```
public class HotelsEntity implements HospitalityEntity{
private int idHotel;
private String name;
private String region;
private String description;
private String photo;

private HotelPropertyEntity property;
private List<RoomEntity> rooms;
private List<ReservationDatesEntity> reservationDates;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotel")
public List<ReservationDatesEntity> getReservationDates() {
    return reservationDates;
}

public void setReservationDates(List<ReservationDatesEntity> reservationDates) {
    this.reservationDates = reservationDates;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_hotel_property")
public HotelPropertyEntity getProperty() {
    return property;
}

public void setProperty(HotelPropertyEntity property) {
    this.property = property;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotel")
public List<RoomEntity> getRooms() {
    return rooms;
}

public void setRooms(List<RoomEntity> rooms) {
    this.rooms = rooms;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id_hotel", unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getIdHotel() {
    return idHotel;
}

public void setIdHotel(int idHotel) {
    this.idHotel = idHotel;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "region")
public String getRegion() {
    return region;
}

public void setRegion(String region) {
    this.region = region;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "description")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "photo")
public String getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(String photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
```

And ReservationDatesEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reservation_dates", schema = "", catalog = "mydb",
    uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id")
    })
public class ReservationDatesEntity implements HospitalityEntity {
private int id;
private long checkIn;
private long checkOut;
private int hotelId;

private HotelsEntity hotel;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn (name = "id_hotel", insertable = false, updatable = false )
public HotelsEntity getHotel() {
    return hotel;
}

public void setHotel(HotelsEntity hotel) {
    this.hotel = hotel;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition="bigint(20)")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "id_hotel", columnDefinition="bigint(20)")
public int getHotelId() {
    return hotelId;
}

public void setHotelId(int hotelId) {
    this.hotelId = hotelId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "check_in", columnDefinition="bigint(20)")
public Long getCheckIn() {
    return checkIn;
}

public void setCheckIn(Long checkIn) {
    this.checkIn = checkIn;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "checkout", columnDefinition="bigint(20)")
public Long getCheckOut() {
    return checkOut;
}

public void setCheckOut(Long checkOut) {
    this.checkOut = checkOut;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Although your log error is not descriptive but it looks like your are trying to eager fetch two lists (with bag semantics) and hibernate does not like this. You can have a workaround using different techniques mentioned [here](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html)

Comment: You are right, I have two OneToMany (in Hotel) bidirectional dependecies with EAGER annotation. I am looking for a solutuin on the blog was provided by you

Comment: It doesn't help, sorry. I use case with Index but still have thje same exception